# Problems with spacing in lstlisting with escaped code

Tags: listings, highlighting

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{title}
\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={!*}{*!},]
int add
int !*\color{red}add*!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the spacing (or the font) in the word inside the escaped code changes. How can I make it to look the same?

I need to change specific parts inside the listing, but the spacing inconsistencies is a problem.

Comment: If the alignment structure of the code allows it, I prefer option `columns=flexible` that sets the spacing more naturally and solves the issue for this instance. However "escaping" means being outside the listings column alignment. Another option could be keyword highlighting and similar.

Comment: Do you want to highglight only the second "add"? Not the first one?

Comment: The problem is that the spacing is changing. I put both to illustrate the problem. Imagine that in a normal usage, the changed part will be surrounded by code, and it will look strange.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: Yes, sorry I got some trouble applying it as I had a custom style. But after a while I made it work. Sorry that I forgot to accept it. :)

Comment: @adn No problem. I was just wondering...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case what you want to highlight is part of the code, my suggestion would be, not to define `!*` and `*!` as escape-to-LaTeX delimiters, but to simply define them as "invisible" delimiters that highlight their content in red, instead. That way, you don't get any discrepancy in column alignment between the normal code and the highlighted code. See my MWE below.

In case the highlighted bit is not code, then I don't think you should concern yourself about such a discrepancy in column alignment. For instance, have a look at the bottom screenshot on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document/158816#158816); do you find anything shocking?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{listings}

% Definition of custom delimiters
% (the `i' means the delimiters themselves don't get printed)
\lstset{moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{!*}{*!}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{title}
\begin{lstlisting}
int add
int !*add*!
\end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that you did good amount of digging into `listings` and code production. Good work. Hope we will get more (like matlab-pretty) :)

Comment: @HarishKumar I still wouldn't claim that I know the `listings` source code well; it's pretty intricate. But once I release matlab-prettifier officially, I might do other similar things with `listings`, if there is a need.