# Underline in lstlisting environment

Tags: listings

I would like to get the same result I get with `\underline` in a `lstlisting` environment.

I was almost sure I got it in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
  language=SQL,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[is][\underbar]{_}{_},
  keepspaces=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myStyle]
SELECT * FROM usr WHERE _id = 7_
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

but when I use the `_` delimiter between `''` it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
  language=SQL,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[is][\underbar]{_}{_},
  keepspaces=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myStyle]
SELECT * FROM usr WHERE id ='_7_'
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `7` should be underlined?

Comment: Yes. In particular I would like to underline words bewteen `''`. For instance, my code doesn't work with `var = '_something_'` but it works with `var = _'something'_`. However, your answer solves this problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There might be easier approaches, but since `lstlisting` is a verbatim environment, `\underline` does not work this way (as any other command would fail too). It's necessary to escape to LaTeX with a user defined escapechar, I chose `%` for this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{upquote}

\lstdefinestyle{myStyle}{
  language=SQL,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[is][\underbar]{_}{_},
  keepspaces=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=myStyle,escapechar=\%]
SELECT * FROM usr WHERE %\underline{id} = \underline{7}%
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This may change the spacing of the identifiers being underlined, when compared to those not underlined.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. Any suggestions to cure this?

Comment: This question solves it, but it turns off any other highlighting you might expect within the delimiters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169612/problems-with-spacing-in-lstlisting-with-escaped-code