# Emphasize hex number in lstlisting using font color

Tags: lstlisting

I'm looking for a way to emphasize specific names and hex numbers in an lstlisting. Using **emph** works for names, but not for hex numbers.

#### What did not work

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
  emph={esp,0xffffcd80},
  emphstyle=\color{red}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xffffd10f       -12017
ecx            0xffffce30       -12752
edx            0xffffce54       -12716
ebx            0x0              0
esp            0xffffcd80       0xffffcd80
ebp            0xffffcdf8       0xffffcdf8
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

which renders the name `esp` in red, but does **not** render the address `0xffffcd80` in the same way, although both are given in the emph option.

[image: lstlisting with emph]

Another approach involves textcolor within an escaped region:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[escapechar=!]
ebx            0x0              0
esp            !\textcolor{red}{0xffffcd80}!       0xffffcd80
ebp            0xffffcdf8       0xffffcdf8
\end{lstlisting}
```

This shows the address in red, but breaks the spacing as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: textcolor in escaped area]

Any ideas how to retain correct spacing/alignment and be able to highlight certain names/addresses in an lstlisting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this answer: [Problems with spacing in lstlisting with escaped code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169612/problems-with-spacing-in-lstlisting-with-escaped-code)

Your code would then look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
  emph={esp},
  emphstyle=\color{red},
  moredelim=[is][\color{red}]{!*}{*!}
}
\begin{lstlisting}
(gdb) info registers
eax            0xffffd10f       -12017
ecx            0xffffce30       -12752
edx            0xffffce54       -12716
ebx            0x0              0
esp            !*0xffffcd80*!       0xffffcd80
ebp            0xffffcdf8       0xffffcdf8
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Which then looks like this:
[image: Render of MWE]